# How to delete "Program Files" and "WindowsApps" folders in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, permissions, filesystems, administrator, users

*I can't delete the folders that are created by Windows.*

One day I switched the place to all new files from disk C to disk D. Then I immediately changed the place back, to disk C.

Windows managed to create a few folders and now I cant't delete them with any way from the Internet. I found similar questions here, but they were not about MY problem.

I don't have the access to delete these folders and any way I tried - and I tried pretty enough - didn't help. I was doing everything as it was said, but it didn't work.

The folders I want to delete are Program Files and WindowsApps. There used to be more folders I wanted to delete and I did following the steps from the Internet either without. The folders are empty and if I delete it nothing will change in my OS, as they don't weight even a byte and aren't used any time.

How can I get the access to delete them or is there any other way to do that? When I try to delete I see the message: "To delete this folder you need to have the administrator's rights". I tried to change the rights of some users, but it didn't help.

P.S. So what I tried: tried many things, so I tell only what I remember: 1. I tried some apps (for example IObit Unlocker, found it here https://answers.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/forum/all/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba/229a678b-a894-40b5-a1cb-0171a56ab9f5), tried to change the owner (worked not with all folders)... And I can not recollect more, sorry. Only these. In some cases it helped, in these it didn't.

Comment: For all the blog post drama of this post there is remarkably little detail. You need to specify what you tried & what happened when you did. "Switched the place" and "from the internet" gives us no clue about your actual predicament or what you have so far tried to solve it.

Comment: I can't remember where I switched it. Ok, I shall edit the post.

Comment: Changed. Sorry for only two details, I can't recollect more, did it long ago.

Comment: [Fix: Cannot Delete WindowsApps folder on Non-System Drives](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/cannot-delete-windowsapps-folder-on-non-system-drives/)

Comment: Wow, I could, but not exactly in this way: on the third step the second command did not work, I don't know why. I tried to jump tu the third, but the commander returned me an error. Then I tried to delete this folder with my hands and, yes, it has worked! Don't you know if I can use the same solution to delete the second problematic folder, "Program Files"? Just I feel scared to do this to the second folder for it is not mentoined there. And could you answer not through a comment but an answer? I wanna mark yours. (i just dont know how to vote it)

Comment: @w32sh doesn't need the points and may not care.  If they don't give you an answer soon, make your own answer using this information, wait a day, and mark it as correct.  BOOM! points for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete the WindowsApps folder on the non-system (D:) drive, run these commands from admin Command Prompt:

```
takeown /f d:\windowsapps /r

icacls d:\windowsapps /grant administrators:F /t

rd d:\windowsapps /s /q
```

*Src: [Fix: Cannot Delete WindowsApps folder on Non-System Drives](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/cannot-delete-windowsapps-folder-on-non-system-drives/)*

You should be able to remove the Program Files folder on the non-system drive using the same way.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. And a remark for those who was mistaken like me: instead of "administrators:F" in the second command try to write <the path to your current user>:F. It may be obviously, but I just didn't get it at once, so...)